# php can connect to remote sql server but command line can't

Tags: mysql

I'm using exactly the same credentials to connect to a remote mysql server.
host % is given to the user.

I can connect via my php application on localhost to remote mysql server

however whenever i do command line on localhost

```
mysql -u username -p'password' -h remoteserver.domain.com
```

it throws an error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'10.50.2.4' (using
 password: YES)
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: Does your username really end in `@`? `username@`?

Comment: i've a typo in my command and error message..

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql command line is wrong. Mysql has the funky syntax of:

```
mysql -u username -ppassword -h remoteserver.domain.com
```

instead of

```
mysql -u username -p password -h remoteserver.domain.com
```

Note the p tag and password placement.

Comment: In the second case, MySQL treat "password" as the database schema you are trying to connect. And as I remember, it will give the user the chance to enter password in the next step.

Comment: Correct, if you just issue the -p with no password attached to it, it will prompt for the pw.

Answer (score 0):

turns out that i should do away single quotes in my password for windows-based mysql command

instead of

```
mysql -u username -p'password' -h remoteserver.domain.com
```

this actually works

```
mysql -u username -ppassword -h remoteserver.domain.com
```

reason why i use single quotes because my password contains non-alpha characters which works in linux but not on windows based command line